# AWS Organization SCP EnforceMFA SSO

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, scp, organization, aws-policies

Looking for a working SCP planted on an Organization Root which enforces MFA for all, but it has problems currently as it does not see STS calls ( SSO ) so for these users even have MFA assuming Organization Administrator roles get denied as MFA not seen by SSO users. of course I used `BoolIfExists: mfaAuthenticationPresent: false` value but this blocks everyone coming via SSO.

Tried `viaService` set to `False` in Deny policy, added `STS:AssumeRoleWithSAML` as exception as `NotAction`.

Comment: `mfaAuthenticationPresent` does not represent whether the SSO provider required MFA, so in SSO configurations it can't effectively be used.  It can only represent MFA devices applied at role assumption time, which in turn requires an MFA device associated with an IAM user.

Comment: Hi, did you test the SCP with different configurations to ensure that both MFA enforcement and SSO functionality work as intended?

Comment: IMO, one approach is to create a more granular SCP that includes specific conditions for SSO users, such as allowing certain actions related to SSO without requiring MFA. By crafting the SCP rules and exceptions, you can achieve the desired security posture without blocking legitimate access.